Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 6.8 crashes on amd ryzen 4500 U
error I recieve when I boot into ubuntuMy laptop is a Dell 7405 with AMD Ryzen 4500 U and keeps crashing with Ubuntu 22.04.
I did not have this issue 6 months ago, and now out of nowhere my system keeps crashing and freezing. Everytime I need to force restart my laptop, which leads to blocks being deleted, and I get prompted into grub menu to manually write fsck commands.
i get the error in the image when I boot into ubuntu and everything stops working
I have tried downgrading to kernel version 6.5.0.45-generic, but when I boot using the older kernel my WiFi and network connection stops working along with dummy audio output and mouse not working.
I am a beginner with Linux and require step by step immediate help
Thanks

I'd be interested seeing some of the answers to this question. I have been suffering freezes and resets for the past year. My computer is literally a Ship of Theseus. Even the case has been swapped out. There are reports that Linux may crash on some AMD processor due to C-states / power management issues. I'm just living w/it. But will likely never buy an AMD processor based board again.

... Ah, I found a Unix/Linux stack exchange post that might help. I'll post it as an answer below. I'll be interested in if it helps w/your situation.

Welcome to ASK. What does the log files say? Append to your question the output of 'last reboot'  Append to your question the result of the following command line 'journalctl --since "2024-11-08 16:07" --until "2024-11-08 16:08" -k' adjust the time just before the event and a bit later. Then do the same thing with the '-p emerg..err' flag. After a reboot with no other interaction check the output of 'free -h' and see if it is creeping up. If it is it suggests a memory leak. You could also try with suspected apps.

This problem is similar to a Unix & Linux Stack Exchange A/Q that can be found here. There is no accepted answer. However, a link from this discussion at forums.debian.net singles out this post in the above answer as a possible solution.
That stack exchange answer contains the following:


you need to update your BIOS and set PSU Idle to Typical Current Idle (this is critical)
kernel parameters for both your computer and all Virtual Machines running on it: idle=nomwait, processor.max_cstate=5
kernel version is important too. Since I am writing this in 2020, make sure you are using the most recent stable kernel



I have updated my bios and did this aswell processor.max_cstate=5 :
but the freezes still persist:
please tell me step by step on how to solve this issue : my current kernel is 6.8.0-45 :

I invite you to come back and answer your question when you have solved your problem! I've done some of these thing already and I still suffer from Ubuntu freezes and reboots. I'll probably never buy an AMD processor again. (If you have enough points you could start a bounty on your question to entice people to post more answers.)

I think I have found a work around !
the kernel 6.8 is still unstable with ryzen chipset with dell hardware :
revert back to an older kernel 6.5 or any from this line of kernel , it will fix the machine freeze  :)
